# Como gerar som no matlab a partir de uma onda?

Tags: matlab, áudio

Se eu criar uma onda senoidal:

- `x=0:0.1:6*pi;` é o range da onda
- `y=sin(x);` é a onda com amplitude 1
- `f=440;` é a frequência desejada

Como gerar um som a partir desses dados?

Tentei `sound(y, f)`, mas não funciona.

Como proceder?

Comment: Não funciona mesmo, ou será que o sinal sonoro que foi tocado é suficientemente perceptível ao ouvido humano? :)  Outra coisa que você precisa ver é se o range é suficientemente longo (me pareceu curto demais para um sinal de áudio) e se a frequência apropriada foi utilizada. Aliás, [na documentação](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sound.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#inputarg_Fs) há uma indicação de que a frequência deveria ser acima de 1000 Hz.

Comment: Mais algumas dicas que podem ser úteis para comparação: http://homepages.udayton.edu/~hardierc/ece203/sound.htm Observe como o som natural não é perfeitamente uma onda senoidal, mas sim uma composição delas, e os valores que você precisa passar pra função são amostras (*samples*) do sinal em um intervalo previamente definido (o *sampling rate* - mais informações sobre isso aqui: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ie7iREcYBPU)

Comment: @LuizVieira isso serve como resposta, não?

Comment: @Math Talvez o primeiro comentário. Mas eu não tenho certeza absoluta do que eu sugeri ser de fato o problema do AP e nem tenho como testar (porque já não tenho mais o Matlab instalado aqui). :)

Answer (score 11):

Faltou tanta coisa, vamos por partes!

```
x=0:0.1:6*pi;
```

Não sei qual foi sua intenção em fazer `6*pi`, não faz nenhum sentido, vc deve ter confundido as coisas, calma que já chego lá...

Seu `x` começa do valor `0` e linearmente vai espaçando os valores com `0.1` até `6*pi = 18.8496`

Pra exemplificar seu `x` é:

```
0    0.1000    0.2000    0.3000    0.4000    0.5000    0.6000 ..... 18.800
```

Isso vai te dar um vetor `x` de tamanho `189`, me parece ser um tamanho muito curto pra escutar qualquer coisa e os valores tbm não refletem a periodicidade que vc deseja...

Sua segunda linha:

```
y=sin(x);
```

sim ela vai gerar uma senoide de tamanho `189` e de acordo com os valores contido em `x`, mas vc já percebeu que os valores do seu `x` não é exatamente o que vc esperava né ...

Terceira linha:

```
f=440;
```

OK vc quer gerar uma senoide a 440Hz

Quarta linha:

```
sound(y, f)
```

Tocar sua senoide `y` na frequência de 440Hz vc acha que é isso ?? humm não é assim que funciona... Na função `sound` o primeiro parâmetro realmente deve ser os valores da senoide/som/etc o segundo parâmetro diz para tocar o som na taxa de amostragem na qual seu vetor foi criado.

**Maneira certa de se fazer:**

Defina quantos segundos de senoide você deseja e defina uma taxa de amostragem(44100, 8000, 2000) qualquer taxa na qual a teoria de [Nyquist](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_da_amostragem_de_Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon) não atrapalhe a faixa humana de percepção audível, algo entre `20hz até 20Khz` em teoria sua taxa de amostragem pode ser de `924hz até 44100hz` (sim 924Hz = `f*2.1` pq vc deseja criar uma senoide a uma frequencia de 440Hz, qualquer coisa abaixo desta taxa de amostragem vai impactar no teorema e vc vai ter problemas, áudio pode começar a ficar intermitente ou o completo silencio).

Mas vamos apelar e usar logo uma `taxa de amostragem = 44100` em teoria (na prática tbm) vai abranger qualquer frequencia até `22050Hz` ou seja todo nosso espectro audível tá dentro :-)

```
segundos=3
Fs=44100;
f=440;
tamanho=segundos*Fs
sinal=1*sin(2*pi*f/Fs*(1:tamanho)); % 1 * sin é a amp, poderia qualquer outro valor de amplitude só coloquei pra exemplificar
sound(sinal, Fs)
```

Repara na fórmula `2*pi*f/Fs` e logo depois é multiplicado pelo vetor que linearmente fica epaçado por `1`.

Depois é só usar o `sound` para escutar.

Comment: Muito boa resposta! :)